# How do I reset the JDK on SQL Developer on Windows?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I was trying to get Oracle SQL developer working on my computer. It prompted me to select my JDK and I selected my v12 JDK. When I try to start I get...

[image]

Where that blacked out part is the JDK12 url. I tried using the `sqldeveloper/bin/sqldeveloper.conf` file using the setJavaHome variable but it doesn't seem to help. I don't have permissions to regedit but my gut is telling me there is a registry value set somewhere.

How do I reset the JDK in Oracle SQL Developer using Windows?

Answer (score 1):

I renamed my JDK12 folder and started the app. It was then reprompting me for the file location of the JDK. Then I changed it back so my env vars didn't need updating.

Answer (score 0):

We don't use the Windows registry, but your gut isn't far off.

For windows, it's defined in your product.conf file found in your OS User's AppData, Roaming Profiles folder.

For Mac/Nix, it'd be in $HOME/.sqldeveloper

Windows:

[image]

Where you see 1.0.0.0 will represent the version of SQL Developer you need to configure the Java home for. I think 1.0 translates to version 4.0, and everything after that should be same as the actual version. I have a 19.4.0 directory for version 19.4 for example.

And a Java12 home for SQL Developer, at least for recent versions will work just fine.

My product.conf for version 19.4 is set to

```
SetJavaHome C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2
```

Comment: I tried this didn't solve it every time it started it just overwrote it even when I changed it

Comment: this is how you set your java home - it doesn't mean there's nothing wrong with your java 12 home though, is that an oracle JDK? also, look for that dll, if you don't see it, copy it to the path that windows is complaining about

Comment: Java 12 works fine for everything else this just doesn't solve the issue. I am telling you on windows it is storing this in a reg value or something (I don't have reg access to confirm). Even if I set it in these files it ignores the value and in the case of the user (AppData) file it overwrites it when the application starts. I am guessing this is a Windows issue. The file it can't find is a dll that isn't included in 12. The file in 12 is called msvcp140.dll.

Moral of the story is this answer didn't work for my issue I had to rename the JDK folder before SQL developer would reprompt.

Comment: It is also a traditional Oracle 12 JDK.

Comment: there's no registry thing going on, i assure you .. maybe you are changing the wrong file, or in the wrong directory

Comment: I know I can't walk you through it so choose to believe whatever you want but I walked through it a bunch of times. I do work in an extremely controlled environment and Windows file system sucks in general but changing those files did not help.

Comment: you can post screenshots of the files you're editing with clear visual of the path so i can confirm you're editing the correct file

Comment: ...\OracleSQLDeveloper\18.20\sqldeveloper\bin\sqldeveloper.conf && ~\AppData\Roaming\sqldeveloper\18.2.0\product.conf

Comment: The AppData one gets overwritten every time it starts and the sqldeveloper.conf just appears to be ignored.

Comment: how about i spin up a web conference, and i'll just talk you through it?

Comment: Any solution? I had exactly the same problem - although I kept editing both files and putting the newly corrected jdk path, every time I launched the executable (any of them) it would get overwritten again in the roaming product.conf file. Finally I solved it by using the suggestion below - just temporarily renaming the bad jdk directory so it couldn't find it anymore, and then it prompted me to select the one I wanted again.